# Updating dictionaries located in other functions

Tags: python, function, dictionary

I'm trying to add items to a dictionary but since the dictionary is in another function they never get updated when I used my addCourses() function.

When calling the addCourses() function I add the functions that contain the dictionaries as arguments in their perspective places, but it doesn't update the original dictionaries so that when I try and getCourseInfo for my new course it is not there.

```
def courseRooms():
    rooms = {'CS101': '3004', 'CS102': '4501', 'CS103': '6755', 'NT110': '1244', 'CM241': '1411'}
    return rooms


def courseInstructors():
    instructors = {'CS101': 'Haynes', 'CS102': 'Alvarado', 'CS103': 'Rich', 'NT110': 'Rich', 'CM241': 'Lee'}
    return instructors


def courseTimes():
    times = {'CS101': '8:00am', 'CS102': '9:00am', 'CS103': '10:00am', 'NT110': '11:00am', 'CM241': '1:00pm'}
    return times


def getCourseInfo(rooms, instructors, times, course):
    if course in rooms:
        print('Course:\t\t', course)
        print('Room:\t\t', rooms.get(course))
        print('Instructor:\t', instructors.get(course))
        print('Time:\t\t', times.get(course))
    else:
        print("Course number not found. Please try again.")


def addCourse(room, instructor, time):
    course = input("Please enter the course number you are trying to add: ").upper()
    room[course] = 'null'
    roomNumber = input("Please enter the room number for that course: ")
    room[course] = roomNumber
    teacher = input("Please enter the instructor for that course: ").title()
    instructor[course] = teacher
    meetingTime = input("Please enter the meeting time for that course: ")
    time[course] = meetingTime
    print("Thank you. That course has been added.")
```

Are the dictionaries not being updated at all or are they just not updating the original ones? It doesn't give me and error but it's not working as intended.

Comment: There's no "original one". Your functions make a new dict every time.

Comment: How these functions are getting called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what I had to do to make this work was to add the dictionaries into my main() function, and then pass them as arguments into each other function using them. Essentially I had to pass them into every function that used the dictionaries, but in my example I've only shown the getCourseInfo() function.
Example:

```
def main():
    try:
        rooms = {'CS101': '3004', 'CS102': '4501', 'CS103': '6755', 'NT110': '1244', 'CM241': '1411'}
        instructors = {'CS101': 'Haynes', 'CS102': 'Alvarado', 'CS103': 'Rich', 'NT110': 'Rich', 'CM241': 'Lee'}
        times = {'CS101': '8:00am', 'CS102': '9:00am', 'CS103': '10:00am', 'NT110': '11:00am', 'CM241': '1:00pm'}

        choice = file.mainMenu()
        while choice != 3:
            if choice == '1':
                course = input("What course number would you like to see info for?: ").upper()
                file.getCourseInfo(rooms, instructors, times, course)

            elif choice == '2':
                course, roomNumber, teacher, time = file.addCourse(rooms, instructors, times)
                rooms[course] = roomNumber
                instructors[course] = teacher
                times[course] = time
                print("Thank you. That course has been added.")

            else:
                print("Thank you. Exiting...")
                exit()

            choice = file.mainMenu()

    except Exception as err:
        print('Error in main: ', err)


def getCourseInfo(rooms, instructors, times, course):
    if course in rooms:
        print('Course:\t\t', course)
        print('Room:\t\t', rooms.get(course))
        print('Instructor:\t', instructors.get(course))
        print('Time:\t\t', times.get(course))
    else:
        print("Course number not found. Please try again.")
```

Answer (score 1):

`rooms` is local variable within function `courseRooms()`, you cannot access it out of the function due to the scope. You can actually assign it out of the function so that other functions can access it. For example,

```
rooms = {'CS101': '3004', 'CS102': '4501', 'CS103': '6755', 'NT110': '1244', 'CM241': '1411'}
instructors = {'CS101': 'Haynes', 'CS102': 'Alvarado', 'CS103': 'Rich', 'NT110': 'Rich', 'CM241': 'Lee'}
times = {'CS101': '8:00am', 'CS102': '9:00am', 'CS103': '10:00am', 'NT110': '11:00am', 'CM241': '1:00pm'}

def getCourseInfo(course):
    if course in rooms:
        print('Course:\t\t', course)
        print('Room:\t\t', rooms.get(course))
        print('Instructor:\t', instructors.get(course))
        print('Time:\t\t', times.get(course))
    else:
        print("Course number not found. Please try again.")


def addCourse():
    course = input("Please enter the course number you are trying to add: ").upper()
    room[course] = 'null'
    roomNumber = input("Please enter the room number for that course: ")
    room[course] = roomNumber
    teacher = input("Please enter the instructor for that course: ").title()
    instructor[course] = teacher
    meetingTime = input("Please enter the meeting time for that course: ")
    time[course] = meetingTime
    print("Thank you. That course has been added.")
```

Comment: This would then essentially make it a global dictionary then, correct? Is there any way to do it without making it global?

Comment: Does above code put inside a class or a module? what do you want to achieve? how did you originally want to call `addCourse(room, instructor, time)`? what are the `room`, `instructor`, `time` you would pass in?

Comment: It's inside a module. Essentially I was hoping to add a course and then have it update the functions at the beginning with new dictionaries. Could I create a function to do that? I'm passing in the functions as parameters room = courseRooms() and so on.

Comment: everytime you call `courseRooms()` it create a new dictionary `rooms`  within the scope of `def courseRooms()` which is not accessible by other functions in the module. If you want to share the access of rooms to both `getCourseInfo()` and `addCourse()`, you have to create a variable in the scope that is shared by both functions, i.e. the module, so that you can pass it around